# How do I stop my hp pavillion from sounding like a live mic?

Tags: windows, audio

My computer is constantly recording or something and everytime I speak I can hear myself as if I were speaking into a microphone on stage somewhere. How can I disable it?

It's driving me crazy, please help!!!

Comment: Is your hp a Windows machine??? If dont please edit your answear.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using your mic a lot? If not, you can unplug it, or if it's an internal mic, you can mute it:

Go to `Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Sounds and Audio Devices -> Voice`, select your device under the 'Recording' list, click 'Volume...' and select 'Mute All' or move the volume slider down all the way.